# Is there a "uniqueness theorem" for non-normal ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I say an ODE $F(x, y, y^{(1)}, \dots , y^{(n)})=0$ is normal if it can be written in a form $y^{(n)} = f(x, y, y^{(1)} , \dots , y^{(n-1)})$.

It is well-known for normal ODEs (satisfying good condition), there's a uniqueness theorem for initial value problem (Picard-Lindelof theorem). This result helps me completely determine the solutions of normal ODEs.

Then, what about non-normal ODEs?

For instance, I learned that $y = xy' - y'^2/4$ (Clairaut's form) has the general solution $y=Cx-C^2/4$ and singular solution $y=x^2$ in my textbook. However, in this case, general solution and singular solution can be "connected" continuously so that there can be another solutions, like $y=x^2(x>0), y=0(x \leq 0)$. My textbook does not mention these ones. I feel weird about this.

I want to determine all the possibility of the solutions of non-normal ODEs. The question is:

(1) Is it possible?
(2) If so, how to do it? Is there a general result?

I'm new to the theory of ODEs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In some neighborhood where the function $F$ satisfies the conditions of the implicit function theorem (w.r.t. the highest derivative), the ODE is normal. But if it is not, the surface defined by $F$ has a degeneracy. There are several possibilities, and they depend on the type of degeneracy.

Comment: For example, imagine a surface defined by $z^2=y$, and a non-degenerate tangent field on it. This field has well-behaved integral curves, but the projections of those curves on the plane $xy$ are really bad. Solutions are not unique everywhere. That’s what happens with equations like $(y’)^2=y$. Clairaut’s equations are very instructive examples too — at least two solutions pass through each point where a solution exists. The best way to deal with non-normal equations is to study them first in their natural habitat — on the surface defined by $F$.